# Push-on coaxial connector with RF leakage performance comparable to threaded-coax connector?

Tags: rf, connector, coax

In examining the performance characteristics of the push-on SMP connector I've noticed that the RF leakage is at best -80dB  @ 3 GHz and then continues to degrade as the frequency increases to -65 dB @ 26.5 GHz, see: [SMP Connector Performance Specifications](http://www.cristek.com/products/microwave/smp/smp-performance-specs.pdf).

This is quite a contrast from a threaded coax-connector such as SMA which has >-100 dB RF leakage across the operating band: [SMA Connector Performance Specifications](http://www.cristek.com/products/microwave/sma/sma-performance-specs.pdf).

Most of the push-on connectors I've seen use a slotted plug design which I suspect is the reason for the increased RF leakage. Does there exist a push-on connector design that is able to achieve comparable levels of RF leakage as a similar threaded connector?

Comment: Did you mean *less-than -100 dB*?

Comment: Probably not, which is why threaded connectors still exist!